# onActivityResult not being called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

The 1st Activity (EditCycle) calls the 2nd activity (EditChooseLists)

```
Intent i=new Intent(EditCycle.this,EditChooseLists.class);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);
```

The 2nd activity (EditChooseLists) is ended as such

```
Toast.makeText(EditChooseLists.this, list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
Intent i=new Intent();
i.putExtra("desc",content);
i.putExtra("content", list.get(position));
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

The 1st Activity (EditCycle) has the method onActivityResult overridden as such

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.print("Test Result !");

    String content=data.getExtras().getString("content");
    System.out.println("result String"+content);
    Toast.makeText(EditCycle.this,content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_editcycle_cropLbl);
    t.setText(content);
}
```

Yet nothing happens when the 2nd activity is resumed, nothing in the console, no toast, textview unchanged

I've concluded that the onActivityResult then is not being called

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Already checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364370/onactivityresult-not-being-called
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492644/onactivityresult-isnt-called-for-startactivityforresult

Comment: Perhaps try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2621390/3249477).

Comment: try to finish then setResult

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);
```

Because `RESULT_OK == -1` and passing a negative value as the second parameter to `startActivityForResult` breaks this promise in the method itself (from the [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))):

> **void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)**
>
> > requestCode `int`: **If >= 0**, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.